# TYPO3 change slug prefix

Tags: typo3, slug

Is it possible to change the prefix of the slug field? There is the url https://www.example.com/MYSLUG. But it should be https://www.example.com/page1/page2/MYSLUG.
I've extended the TCA with this:

```php
'appearance' => [
  'prefix' => \VENDOR\EXT\UserFunctions\FormEngine\SlugPrefix::class . '->getPrefix'
],
```

and it looks like this:

```php
use TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Form\FormDataProvider\TcaSlug;

    class SlugPrefix
    {
        public function getPrefix(array $parameters, TcaSlug $reference): string
        {
            return '';
        }
    }
```

So now the prefix is empty. How can I set the prefix to an URL? I have the ID of the URL in the typoscript setup.

Comment: why can you not do it in your config.yaml?

Comment: what do you mean? i would like to show the right prefix

Comment: It's a bit hard to follow without context. I guess you want to change what is shown in the backend for a record with a "slug" field. I also thought first your problem was about a page and about the generated URL.

Comment: No the url is being generated correctly. You are right. I want to show an other link (prefix) for the generated url

Comment: I think you should specify your version of TYPO3 and where you want what to see. I'm suspecting you want something which is built in in a newer version, but I might be wrong.  Maybe you explain the term `prefix` how you understand it as it could mean different things depending on context.

Comment: Im using TYPO3 Version 11.5. If you add a slug field to yout CTA you get this field in your extension.

Comment: Question seems to be about the user functions content and how to get an absolute URL to a page defined in TS, so this URL can be returned as prefix.

Comment: Exactly. Thats right.